# JPA EmptyResultDataAccessException handling

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a simple library API for a college project. I have a database with books, each with it's own ID. I'm using Spring Boot to make the service. I have a `BookRepository` which extends `JpaRepository<Book, Long>`, and a service implementation.

```
@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService{

   @Autowired
   private BookRepository bookRepository;

   @Async
   @Override
   public void delete (Long id){
       bookRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Later on, a REST controller handles the request:

```
@RestController
public class BookServiceController{

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @RequestMapping(value="books/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Book> deleteBook (@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        bookService.delete(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Book>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Now, if I were to delete a Book which is not in the database, for example with an ID of 123, I'd get a EmptyResultDataAccessException thrown.

My question is, how and where do I handle the exception, and how do I avoid casting a NullPointerException that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Is there a reason you're layering a separate `BookService` over the repository? (2) Prefer constructor injection to field injection whenever possible.

Answer (score 6):

The most elegant way to avoid the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` is to define an specific method in your `Repository` interface to delete by your id field.

Let's supppose that your id field is named bookId:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
    Long deleteByBookId(Long bookId);
}
```

In this way the exception won't be throwed.

I haven't tested the solution if your id field is simply called id.

Comment: This approach should be accepted as the right answer too.

Comment: This probably only works if the Book has "bookId" named id field. Otherwise (for "id" field) you have no way to override the default implementation.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of a `DELETE` operation, you aren't really returning an entity anymore; you're simply confirming that the resource is gone. As `DELETE` is idempotent (you could delete the record multiple times), you can either return the same status code regardless of whether the record exists or return a 404 if the record isn't found. You can also simplify the handler method:

```
@DeleteMapping("/books/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) // because you deleted it
public void deleteBook(@PathVariable Long id) {
    try {
        bookService.delete(id); // or just use the repository directly
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
        // either do nothing to return a 204, or
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}
```

where you have an exception that indicates the status:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {}
```

It's plausible that `EmptyResultDataAccessException` should *already* be annotated with a status of `NOT_FOUND`; this is a potential enhancement request.

Comment: I've tried this, and it returns an EmptyResultDataAccessException anyway.

Comment: I am still getting EmptyResultDataAccessException even after using this solution

Comment: Conventionally DELETE method is idempotent, i.e. not throwing NotFound if not found.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate exception handler that uses using @ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler({ EmptyResultDataAccessException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleResourceNotFound(Exception ex, WebRequest req) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
            ex.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        );
    }
}
```

And you could then simplify your delete endpoint by removing the conditional:

```
@DeleteMapping("/books/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteBook(@PathVariable Long id) {
    bookRepository.delete(id)
}
```

The [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) [approach](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) has the advantage of responding to all controllers, for a unified, application level exception handler. The above handler will by default handle EmptyResultDataExceptions from all controllers.