# Spring Data JPA - Exception thrown when using DeleteById with a non existing id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using a spring data JPA with a Postgresql db. I have an elementary table, a primary key (varchar) and some attributes. I have a repository and a service using this repository.

I am facing an issue when using deleteById or by using deleteAllById. Indeed, the method should ignore a non-existing id. But when I'm using one of those methods an exception is thrown **EmptyResultDataAccessException**.

I would like to know how to set jpa to ignore if an id doesn't exist in my table as explained in the doc of **CrudRepository**.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA EmptyResultDataAccessException handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233648/jpa-emptyresultdataaccessexception-handling)

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran it partialy answer my question. Ill do that but i still don't understand why those methods throws an exception when they have to ignore this case. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are hit by https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2719

Fixed in 3.0.2+

Answer (score -1):

You can handle the case like this

```
public void deleteById(String id) {
    if (yourEntityRepository.existsById(id)) {
        yourEntityRepository.deleteById(id);
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the entity does not exist
        // You can throw a custom exception or perform any other logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Why make two DB trips when one can simply catch the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` and move on?

Answer (score -3):

there is a sample code hope it work :

```
try{
if(repository.existsById(id){
   repository.deleteById(id);
}
}catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex){
throws new NotFoundException
}
```

Comment: Which is what Spring Data actually does, and isn't what he wants.

Comment: Yes I was wrong . now I fix my code . could you please check again